# Как реализовать авто прием заявок в тг канал?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Часто вижу во многих тг каналах такую систему: ты кликаешь на вступительную ссылку она предлагает тебе подать заявку. После подачи заявки она моментально принемается + к тебе стучится бот с названием по типу прием заявок228 и кидает тебе рекламму.

Стало интересно как это реализовать, возможно средствами aiogram или какой-нибудь другой либы . Решения в инете не нашел, по этому прошу помощи у читающих. За помощ буду благодарен.

Comment: Уже есть такой вопрос

Comment: Киньте ссылку пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Я бы решил вопрос так: (aiogram)

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def join_request(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    user_id=update.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(user_id, 'Реклама')
    #тут можно добавить пользователя в бд для дальнейших рассылок
    await update.approve() #.decline() если отклоняем
```

Comment: P.S. Боту требуется разрешение приема заявок, ссылка должна быть с параметром "одобрение администратором канала"